# JQuery 'find' method not working

Tags: jquery

In following HTML, I want to change the background of `<li>` using JQuery. But it is not working. The code works if I hard-code the background value in CSS.

My CSS. Using JQuery's find method, I want to assign `li.tmpFound` class to `<li>` elements which should change the background color

```
body {
 font: 24px sans-serif;
}


ul#tmpFavorites {
 list-style:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

a {
 text-decoration:none;
}


ul#tmpFavorites li {
 padding: 3px;
 margin: 1px;
}


li.tmpFound {
    background: yellowgreen;
}
```

JS code

```
if ($) {

$(document).ready (
 function(){
  /* assign the class after finding all li*/
  $('ul#tmpFavorites').find('li').addClass('li.tmpFound');

 }
);


}
```

HTML - contains a ul and 2 li

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>


    <style type="text/css">

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Example 1-1c.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Example 1-1c.css">
</head>
<body>

<ul id="tmpFavorites">
    <li><a href="http://www.amazon.com">Amazon</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('ul#tmpFavorites').find('li').addClass('tmpFound');
```

You can't pass a selector to `.addClass()` but a name. So instead of `li.tmpFound`, use `tmpFound`. The issue is not that you can not pass a name that looks like a selector, you can. As your code shows, the class "li.tmpFound" will be added. But you just want to add the class `tmpFound` as is clear from your CSS. So use that instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul#tmpFavorites').find('li').addClass('tmpFound');
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 24px sans-serif;
}

ul#tmpFavorites {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#tmpFavorites li {
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
}

li.tmpFound {
  background: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tmpFavorites">
  <li><a href="http://www.amazon.com">Amazon</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
</ul>
```